# Import library in robot framework as another name?

Tags: robotframework

I wonder that how can we import library as another name in robot framework?

For example: I want to import **Selenium2Library** as name "**SL**"

So what do I need to do?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should import like this

```
Library    Selenium2Library    WITH NAME    SL
```

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-custom-name-to-test-library

Comment: Thank Zverev, but in my case, how you can manage 2 library which have same keywords. For example, When test fail, RF will automatically run Capture Screen shoot (by default). I've added another lib and it also has Capture Screen Shoot. So test will fail because (**Duplicated keyword!**).

Answer (score 0):

@MinhNguyen-Phuong-Hoang You could try importing each library with a different name and then specify the keyword you want with a fully qualified name.

```
Library    SeleniumLibrary     WITH NAME    SL
Library    Selenium2Library    WITH NAME    SL2

    SL2.Capture Screen
```